# Arriving at the energy functional of the nonlinear Poisson equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I'm self studying some variational methods for PDEs but I'm really lost on the process of looking to a PDE and saying "this is the energy functional which Euler-Lagrange equation is the PDE". For example, almost every textbook I've read says that the functional

$$
I[u] = \int_\Omega {1 \over 2}|\nabla u|^2 - F(x , u(x)) dx,
$$

where

$$
F(x, s) = \int_0^t f(x, s) ds,
$$

is the functional associated with the nonlinear Poisson equation

$$
-\Delta u = f(x, u).
$$

I don't get where this comes from. Like, I see that the Fréchet derivative of $I[u]$ is basically the weak formulation of the nonlinear Poisson equation, what I don't see is the process of looking to such PDE and saying that $I[u]$ is the functional we want. I thought that it'd be something like "just take $v = u$ in the weak formulation" but it's not quite clicking. I reckon it's probably something trivial that I'm not seeing, but if you guys could give some clarification or point to some references It'd be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MatthewCassell how come $\int_\Omega f(x,u)u = \int_\Omega F(x, u(x))$? It's mainly this that was bothering me when taking $u = v$

Comment: It's still not making much sense... Is there a way to show that $fu = F$ in the general case?

Comment: Due to comment character constraints and the fact I'm typing on a phone, I made a few omissions in the last comment that probably confused you and so I removed it. I'll come back to this question tomorrow if no one answers it. In the mean time, just know that because the forcing $f$ is dependent on $u$, when you minimise the functional with respect to $u$ you need to use the integral of the forcing so that the fundamental theorem of calculus returns the specific $f$ you are after.

Comment: Sure, thanks anyway, is clearing up slowly.

Comment: Perhaps a direct computation makes it clearer \begin{align} I[u] &=\int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{2}\lvert\nabla u\rvert^{2}-F(x,u)dx \\ \implies \delta I&=\frac{d}{d \epsilon}\left( \int_{\Omega}\frac{1}{2} \lvert \nabla (u + \epsilon \phi) \rvert^{2} - F(x, u + \epsilon \phi) dx \right) \bigg \lvert_{\epsilon = 0} \end{align} The derivative with respect to $\epsilon$ in the first term yields
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \lvert \nabla (u + \epsilon \phi) \rvert \cdot \frac{\nabla (u + \epsilon \phi)}{\lvert \nabla (u + \epsilon \phi) \rvert} \cdot \nabla \phi = \nabla (u + \epsilon \phi) \cdot \nabla \phi$$

Comment: The derivative in the second term yields $$\phi \ \partial_{2} F(x, u + \epsilon \phi)$$ where $\partial_{2}$ denotes the derivative with respect to the second coordinate. Hence \begin{align}
\delta I &= \int_{\Omega} \nabla (u + \epsilon \phi) \cdot \nabla \phi - \phi \ \partial_{2} F(x, u + \epsilon \phi) dx \bigg \lvert_{\epsilon = 0} \\
&= \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \phi - \phi \ \partial_{u} F(x, u) dx
\end{align} To get our original PDE, we require $\partial_{u} F = f$ and hence $F = \int f du$.

Comment: I just noticed. Where does the division by 2 comes from on the integration by parts in your first response? Jesus, I'm feeling kinda hopeless here lol

Comment: Don't feel hopeless, _I made a mistake there_. Multiplication by $u$ and integration by parts should yield $$\int_{\Omega} (\lvert \nabla u \rvert^{2} - fu) dx$$ i.e the Dirichlet energy is missing the $1/2$ prefactor. This is why I shouldn't have written my original comments on a phone, it is too difficult to see any errors I made.

Comment: Oh thank God. Thanks for the heads up